# How to get access to Azure VM image created in one azure account on another?

Tags: azure, entra-domain-services, azure-backup, azure-image

We have created a specialized VM image in Azure and shared it in shared image gallery in one of the azure accounts our organization has(ex: userA@company.com). Question is, how can this image be made available on another azure account under the same organization(ex: userB@company.com). We need to create VM under the azure account (UserB@company.com) based off of the image created in azure account (UserA@company.com). How can we accomplish this? All the documentation for this seems a vague atleast to us, so it would be great if someone can direct us on how to do this. Thanks in advance.

edit: Both Azure accounts are under a single subscription and AAD.

Comment: Please add details about the Azure *subscriptions* and if they are linked to the same Azure AD or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two users from the same AAD are accessing the same Azure subscription, they should see the same objects; this includes the shared image gallery.

Check that both users have proper access rights; they will need at least Reader access, either to the subscription as a whole, or to the specific objects they need to use.

Comment: Thank you, we've assigned reader role and now it started showing up